# Endless upcoming text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My task is to create the page with text blocks upcoming endless inside the div block.
Here is my solution:

```
  <script>
            var startOffset = 0;
            var startOffsetPlus;
            var startOffsetMinus;
            $(document).ready(function () {

                startOffset = $(".carousel-item").last().offset().top;
                startOffsetPlus = "+="+ startOffset +"px";
                startOffsetMinus = "-="+ startOffset +"px";
                //endless loop call
                setInterval('beginEndlessLoop()', 1000/*Starting delay in ms*/);
            });
            function beginEndlessLoop(){
                setInterval('moveTextUp()', 0 /*ms*/);
            }
            function moveTextUp() {
                $(".carousel-block").animate(
                    {"top": startOffsetMinus}, 
                    {
                        duration: 10000/*ms*/, 
                        easing: "linear"}
                    );
                //move blocks to start position
                $(".carousel-block").animate({"top": startOffsetPlus}, 0/*ms*/);
            }
</script>
```

This solution works fine. But One problem is that this script takes processor and memory more and more. I'm not a javascript programmer. Could anyone please tell me how to call Garbage collector or something? =)

Comment: You should really look up what setInterval does. This will give you the first clue on why your app is dying. Your code has to be totally rewritten and basically at this point, you are asking someone to write your code for you rather than asking a question.

Comment: @Anubis What to expect after you have created an endless loop? Endless waste of CPU time and memory, ofcourse.

Comment: @dku.rajkumar: sorry I don't understand you.

Comment: @kitgui.com: the only thing I'm asking is Is anyone worked with endless jquery animation and could give me a advice. I'm not asking to do something to me. I already did this thing.

Comment: @Teemu: I expect that every loop iteration will use the same memory and cpu as the previous one.

Comment: If so, you have to clear the first call, by naming it and then add `clearInterval('interval_name');` as first row in `beginEndlessLoop()`. Now you create one endless loop once per second.

Comment: I just did an animation with "endless loop" last night but in an AJAX way. Maybe the code will help you, maybe not. Its super tiny and simple to understand. See www.zipstory.com and view source for intro.js. This is a live update app that queues updates so they don't all appear at once and does so in a smooth way that doesn't burn CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Works!

```
 <script>
            var startOffset = 0;
            var startOffsetPlus;
            var startOffsetMinus;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                startOffset = $(".carousel-item").last().offset().top;
                startOffsetPlus = "+="+ startOffset +"px";
                startOffsetMinus = "-="+ startOffset +"px";
                window.setTimeout(function(){moveTextUp()}, 3000);
            });
            function moveTextUp() {
                $(".carousel-block").animate({"top": startOffsetMinus}, 10000, 'linear', function() {
                    $(".carousel-block").animate({"top": startOffsetPlus}, 0);
                    moveTextUp();
                });
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need setInterval()

use callback in $.animate

```
function moveTextUp()
{
 $(".carousel-block").animate(
                    {"top": startOffsetMinus}, 
                    {
                        duration: 10000/*ms*/, 
                        easing: "linear",
                        complete: moveTextUp
                    }

                    );
}
```

Comment: the same result. memory and cpu usage is increasing

Comment: try complete: setTimeout( moveTextUp, 500 )